# Wordpress php and html

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Sublime text shows the error and when I inspect the web browser, is this line wrong? but I can not see the error
The line start $output .= '

```
<article class="post">
    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title();?></a></h2>

    <p class="post-info"><?php the_time('F j, Y G:i '); ?> | by <a href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta('ID')); ?>"><?php the_author(); ?></a>| Posted in 

        <?php

        $categories = get_the_category( );
        $separator = ", ";
        $output = '';

        if ($categories){

            foreach ($categories as $category ) {

             $output .= '<a href="' . get_the_category_link($category->term_id) . '">' . $category->cat_name . '</a>' . $separator;

            }

            echo trim($output, $separator);
        }

        ?>

        </p> 

    <?php the_content(); ?> 
</article>  

<?php endwhile;

else :
    echo '<p>No content found</p>';

endif;

get_footer();

?>
```

Comment: Add are we supposed to guess what the error is ?

Comment: Could you post the error so we can see what it say, please?

Comment: Sublime text marks up the <a href.. on this line   $output .= '<a href="' . get_the_category_link($category->term_id) . '">' . $category->cat_name . '</a>' . $separator;   I don´t now why? but on the browser Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_the_category_link() in.  I am a newbie, but hope I can explain it as good as possible. Grateful for all the help I can get

Comment: They error you're getting is because the function 'get_the_catgory_link' is not actually a Wordpress function. I think the one you're looking for might be `get_category_link()` instead.

Comment: Finally, the problem solved ..... If I use get_category_link and not .... get_the_category link it works.

Comment: @Riesbeck So you problem is now fixed?

Comment: Yes Andy Henderson....the problem is fixed, a major problem with a simple solution :) I am a newbie who does not understand much, but I learn something new every day. Very grateful and very happy at how people spend their time to help each other.

Comment: @Riesbeck Glad to have been of help! Feel free to [accept my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if you feel it was useful to you. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said you are getting the following error.

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_the_category_link() in...

This means that the function you are calling is not defined (PHP doesn't know what you want it to do with this function).

I think you are just using the wrong function name. You want to use this '`get_category_link()` instead of `get_the_category_link()`. Wordpress has already defined the `get_category_link()` function for you so you shouldn't get the undefined function error with this one.